# Pros and cons to having two advisors

Tags: graduate-school, advisor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages and disadvantages of having multiple advisers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-having-multiple-advisers)

What are the advantages to having a single advisor vs having two co-advisors?